# drush sql-sync fails with PHP Fatal Error

Tags: drush

drush sql-sync @devyau @stageyau returns:

> Unable to load class Drupal\Driver\Database\Drush
>    PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function dump() on a
>   non-object in
>   /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc on line
>   275

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

> Error: Call to a member function dump() on a non-object in
>   /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc, line
>   275

Comment: what verion of Drupal is this (I think I know, but I don't want to 'guess' what the question is actually about ...)? And what version of Drush are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7.38 and Drush 7.0.0. Fixed my alsias files and moved Directory /var/www/vhosts/stage.youngamericansunited.net>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FNAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
        </Directory>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My alias file was the problem:

```
<?php
$aliases['devyau'] = array(
'uri'=> 'dev.[sitename]',
'root'=> '/var/www/vhosts/dev.[sitename]/',
'db-url' => 'mysql://[username]:[password]/devDBname',
  ); 
?>
```

My alias file apparently didn't have enough data to function.

See my previous question at:
    [drush sql-sync fails](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164242/drush-sql-sync-fails)

burnsjeremy provided this model alias file, which answered my question and allowed me to use Drush again! Thanks!

```
$remote_sites = '/path/to/site'; // usually /var/www/drupal-root-name
$aliases['site.dev'] = array(
 'uri' => 'sitename.com',
 'remote-host' => '{ip to remote}',
 'remote-user' => '{remote ssh user}',
 'root' => $remote_sites,
 'ssh-options' => '-p {if you ssh in on another port like 2222}',
 'path-aliases' => array(
 '%drush-script' => '/root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush', // This is so you can  
 have multiple drush installs and use different ones on different sites.
 'php'=> '/usr/local/bin/php', // Again if you have different php's for 
 different sites.
 '%site' => 'sites/default/', // This is the important part here, it will       
 ensure the proper bootstrap
 '%dump-dir' => '/path/to/drush.dbdumps', // This is where you want to dump 
 your databases, normally /tmp folder I think.
 '%files' => $remote_sites . '/files' // Your sites file folder, incase it is 
 somewhere else.
),
// You may actually need this, especially if you are running D7 since I     
   haven't ever tested the db-url thing on D7 or above. 
 'databases' => array (
   'default' => array (
    'default' => array (
     'driver' => 'mysql',
     'database' => '{db_name}',
     'username' => '{db_user}',
     'password' => '{db_pass}',
   ),
  ),
 ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you run this command on console. if command is run successfully after then you check your drush library, I think this is drush library problem.

Second is you can try other command like :-

drush ard

Comment: drush ard returns The external command could not be executed due to an application error.                                                                                              [error]
Unable to determine sites directory for devyau

Comment: How do I fix a drush library problem...have searched all over and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that your remote alias is correctly declared:

```
$aliases['remote'] = array (
  'root' => 'absolute_path_to_your_drupal',
  ...
)
```

try other commands like

```
drush @devyau uli
drush @stageyau uli
```

If doesn't work the path may be the problem.

Comment: I'm working with the devyau stageyau and prodyau directly on the server...not running Drush on my desktop computer

Comment: drush @devyau uli and stage uli return:PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function db_spec() on boolean in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc on line 370

Comment: OH, I see...my remote aliases ARE OK. THey are on the server.

Comment: drush ard returns: Call to undefined function drush_sql_get_class() in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc on line 366

Comment: echo $PATH returns: /root/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Comment: drush @devyau uli returns: 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function drush_sql_get_class() in /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc on line 366

Comment: And do your remote server has drush installed?